# How to look for user who updated JIRA issue using jira-python?

Tags: jira, python-jira

I don't seem to have the permissions to view the transitions on issues.

The commonly used snippet: *[(t['id'],t['name']) for t in j.transitions(issue)]* returns an empty list on a valid issue. I can see the issue, its transitions from the Web interface.

When the issue is in the "Fixed" state, I would like to find which user changed it from "Assigned" to "Fixed". Here is my workflow:

[image: jira_simple_workflow]

How do I achieve this with python-jira?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Insert the following.  I use python-3 so you may have to adjust your print statement formats.

```
issue = jira.issue('project-682', expand='changelog') changelog = 
issue.changelog

for history in changelog.histories:
    for item in history.items:
        if item.field == 'status':
            print ('Date:',history.created,' From:',item.fromString, 'To:',item.toString, ' By: ',history.author)
```